# Symfony unique violation.....key xxxxx already exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I was ask to take back the code of a person who left the firm some months ago.
He developped an app to permit some people to ask for changes to a firewall rules
When tou ask a change, you can select/fill:
firewall name (correspond to firewall interface) 
Port
Source address
destination address
Service type (TCP/UDP/ICMP)

There are 2 tables in database:

```
Rule                                         FW
----------                                   ---------
ID                                           ID
Fw_Id                                        Name
idrule                                       Description
Port                                         ----------
Source Address 
Destination Adress
Service Type
----------
```

there's only 1 firewall/rule and 1 rule/firewall

my problem comes when i try to save the form, doctrine tries to save all the firewall informations not only the id and tells there's a unique key violation.
i searched but can't figure out what's wrong

the Rule Entity:

```
<?php

namespace FWBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* Rule
*
* @ORM\Table(name="rule", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_fw_id", columns={"fw_id", "idrule"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FwBundle\Repository\ruleRepository")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"fw","idrule"}, message="Rule already exists")
*/

class Rule
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FwBundle\Entity\fw")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fw_id",referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $fw;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idrule", type="integer")
     */
    private $idrule;
```

The FW Entity:

```
<?php

namespace FWBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * fw
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fw")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FWBundle\Repository\FwRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message="Firewall already exists.")
 */
class Fw
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
```

The RuleController:

```
public function AddAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $namespace = 'FwBundle';
    $em = thiss->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repositoryRule = $em->getRepository($namespace.':Rule');
    $repositoryFw = $em->getRepository($namespace.':Fw');

    $rule = new rule();

    $form = $this->createForm(RuleType::class, $rule,array('fw'=>$id));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
        if    ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $rule = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($rule);
            $em->flush();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with your Rule form class ?

Comment: Can you add your RuleType form too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rule` can only be linked to one `Firewall` and one `Firewall` can be  linked to a one `Rule`. What you are trying to do is linking many `Rule`s to a single `Firewall`.

You should probably consider changing `OneToOne` relationship to `ManyToOne` like that a Firewall could have many Rules and the error should disappear ( you have to update your database schema before of course)

If you are sure that `OneToOne` is the one you want you should not create a new Rule in your form if the Firewall already have one.

Your code should be similar to this :

```
public function AddAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $namespace = 'FwBundle';
    $em = thiss->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repositoryRule = $em->getRepository($namespace.':Rule');
    $repositoryFw = $em->getRepository($namespace.':Fw');

    $rule = new rule(); // remove this line and change it with the two lines below
    $fw = $repositoryFw->find($id); // assuming that id is the id of firewall
    $rule = $fw->getRule() ? : new Rule(); // if Firewall has a rule entity then take it otherwise create a new one. 

    $form = $this->createForm(RuleType::class, $rule,array('fw'=>$id));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
        if    ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $rule = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($rule);
            $em->flush();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried your suggestions but got errors telling me  the form should use Rule's entity but use Doctrine Collection.

Comment: yes and after the view problem, i have a persistence problem some elements in my form are not persisted